# Kotlin retroactively applied Interface

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in Kotlin to retroactively apply an interface or have a function/Type act like that?

I use a generator to generate multiple classes. The generator does not allow to declare an interface that these classes implement. Instead, they all just implement the same functions. Let's call the classes A, B and C.

A, B and C all have functions called f1, f2 and f3, but they are individually implemented and are *not* the result of an interface implementation.

Now, I want to declare a function that takes some type, acting like an interface, as a parameter, which would fit A, B and C and is able to use f2 and f3. I've seen a [question similar to this one](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/implicit-interfaces/149) on the Kotlin website but could not find anything that works like this.

Apparently Go is able to do something like that. Although it's a little oddly formed and the `close` function is not used, so it might not exactly show what I want to do here.

I look for something like this:

```
class A {
   fun f1 (string: String) {}
   fun f2 (int: Int) {}
   fun f3 () {}
}

class B {
   fun f1 (string: String) {}
   fun f2 (int: Int) {}
   fun f3 () {}
}

class C {
   fun f1 (string: String) {}
   fun f2 (int: Int) {}
   fun f3 () {}
}
```

Note again: No interface implementation for either of these classes.

And I want to have a function that works for all of them. Something like this:

```
typeContract CollectiveABC {
   fun collectiveF2 (int: Int) {}
   fun collectiveF3 () {}
}
```

Or this

```
collectiveType CollectiveABC {
   classes: A, B, C
   collectiveF2: A.f2, B.f2, C.f2
   collectiveF3: A.f3, B.f3, C.f3
}
```

To be used like this:

```
fun collectiveUse(objABC: CollectiveABC) {    // <- Collective type used here allows for defining one behaviour for all three classes
   obj.collectiveF2(12345)
   obj.collectiveF3()
}

fun use() {
   collectiveUse(A())
   collectiveUse(B())
   collectiveUse(C())
}
```

I know I can pass the respective functions as parameters like this:

```
fun collectiveUse(f1: (String) -> Unit, f2: (Int) -> Unit, f3: () -> Unit) { ... }

fun use() {
   val a = A()
   val b = B()
   val c = C()

   collectiveUse(a::f1, a::f2, a::f3)
   collectiveUse(b::f1, b::f2, b::f3)
   collectiveUse(c::f1, c::f2, c::f3)
}
```

But as you can see, these functions make the function head a bit long and generally don't scale too well. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a subclass of each class and implement the interface there?

Comment: @Sweeper pretty good point. Not exactly what I was looking for but definitely a good second pick. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference extending a class than implementing an interface?

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, interfaces can contain both abstract method declarations and method implementations. The fact that interfaces cannot store state distinguishes them from abstract classes. They are allowed to have attributes, but they must be abstract or give accessor implementations.

I am a beginner and that is all I know.

Comment: Not quite the point. I understand how interfaces and abstract classes work. The thing is, I want classes, which I can not change, which all look the same on the outside, to act as if they have the same base.